# How to add external data to javascript for jquery auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to make a auto complete search bar using jquery autocomplete. The thing is I need to display Json data from an external site into my search bar.

Whenever I try to put the data as such from json into the script, it's working. But when I refer external url it refuses to work.

I tried implementing all json data into my script. But it takes so long to process as there will be more than 40000+ lines in my html page.

The Json link for the data which I have to display is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rreichel3/US-Stock-Symbols/main/nasdaq/nasdaq_full_tickers.json)

```js
<script>
            $('#id_ticker').autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        var data = {
          "success": true,
          "data": [
          {
            "symbol": "AACG",
            "name": "ATA Creativity Global American Depositary Shares",
            "lastsale": "$2.19",
            "netchange": "-0.45",
            "pctchange": "-17.045%",
            "volume": "1408435",
            "marketCap": "68715455.00",
            "country": "China",
            "ipoyear": "",
            "industry": "Service to the Health Industry",
            "sector": "Miscellaneous",
            "url": "/market-activity/stocks/aacg"
          },
          {
            "symbol": "AACI",
            "name": "Armada Acquisition Corp. I Common Stock",
            "lastsale": "$9.88",
            "netchange": "0.01",
            "pctchange": "0.101%",
            "volume": "8345",
            "marketCap": "204609860.00",
            "country": "United States",
            "ipoyear": "2021",
            "industry": "",
            "sector": "",
            "url": "/market-activity/stocks/aaci"
          }],
          "additional_data": {
            "pagination": {
              "start": 0,
              "limit": 5,
              "more_items_in_collection": true,
              "next_start": 5
            }
          }
        };
        
        var datamap = data.data.map(function(i) {
          return {
            label: i.symbol + ' - ' + i.name.split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' '),
            value: i.symbol,
            desc: i.title
          }
        });
        
        var key = request.term;
        
        datamap = datamap.filter(function(i) {
          return i.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        });
    
        response(datamap);
      },
      minLength: 1,
      delay: 500
    });
    </script>
```

The above code works and the below code doesn't.

```
    <script>
        $('#id_ticker').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var data = {
      "success": true,
      "data": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rreichel3/US-Stock-Symbols/main/nyse/nyse_full_tickers.json"
      ],
      "additional_data": {
        "pagination": {
          "start": 0,
          "limit": 5,
          "more_items_in_collection": true,
          "next_start": 5
        }
      }
    };
    
    var datamap = data.data.map(function(i) {
      return {
        label: i.symbol + ' - ' + i.name.split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' '),
        value: i.symbol,
        desc: i.title
      }
    });
    
    var key = request.term;
    
    datamap = datamap.filter(function(i) {
      return i.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });

    response(datamap);
  },
  minLength: 1,
  delay: 500
});
</script>
```

Looking for a solution to add this and also for a solution to reduce the json key pair with only "symbol" and "name" from each corresponding data in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function toAutocomplete(dt, keyvar){
  let rli = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) rli.push(dt[i][keyvar]);
  return rli;
}

function inArrayAutocompleteSelected(key, array_autocomplete, array_master){
  let x = array_master[$.inArray(key, array_autocomplete)];
  return x;
}

$('#id_ticker').autocomplete({ source: [], minLength: 1 });  
// $('#id_ticker').autocomplete("disable");


let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rreichel3/US-Stock-Symbols/main/nyse/nyse_full_tickers.json';
let r = _ajax('GET', url, ''); // your ajax script
console.log(r);

let liAuto = toAutocomplete(r, 'name');
console.log(liAuto);
$('#id_ticker').autocomplete("option", "source", liAuto );

// $('#id_ticker').autocomplete("enable");
$("#id_ticker").autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui, ui.item);        
    getData = inArrayAutocompleteSelected(ui.item.value, liAuto, r);
    console.log(getData);
  }
});
```